# hello. what version is recommend for a iMac G5 2006 Intel (yes. a intel system)

Tags: mac

what version is recommend for a iMac G5 2006 Intel (yes. a intel system) so that i can get some use out of it for the first time after sitting in a storage of a school. then next to my main system Just so i can Use it for a acual need like a microphone and such

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the "G5" refers specifically to the PowerPC G5 chip which is **not** an Intel CPU.

If you actually have a G5 CPU, there are no longer any supported versions of Ubuntu for that PPC architecture.  Similarly for 32-bit CPUs, even Intel chips, there are no longer any supported versions of Ubuntu for that architecture. Both of these types of CPUs are very old at this point and it is simply too much work to produce these versions to accommodate for the very few people still running these CPU architectures.  However there are other distros that support PPC and 32-bit CPUs, like Debian.

Now, if you have a 64-bit Intel CPU you can use whatever version of Ubuntu you want.  There are several official [flavours](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours). If you are concerned that a particular desktop environment will be too heavy and sluggish, Xfce (Xubuntu) and LXQt (Lubuntu) are generally less resource-intensive than the other flavors.